# A finite set $S$ containing no perfect powers such that, for any prime $p$, $x^n\equiv s\pmod{p}$ has a solution $(x,s)\in\mathbb{Z}\times S$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that there exists a finite set $S$ of positive integers greater than $1$ with the following properties:

1. No element of $S$ may be expressed as $a^b$ with $a,b>1$.
2. For any prime $p$ there exists $s \in S$ and $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^n \equiv s \ (\text{mod} \ p)$.

**Note that the fact that cardinality of the set $S$ is greater than $1$ is a nontrivial problem in itself which requires Chebotarev density theorem, so any ideas?**

For context, the case $n=2$ can be satisfied by $S=\{2,3,6\}$.

Comment: Do you have an example of $S$ when $n=2$?  I think $S=\{2,3,6\}$ might work.

Comment: Take S={2,3,6}.

Comment: The thing is even moving from n=2 case to further requires something different

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots$ be an enumeration of the prime natural numbers.  Take $S$ to be the set of integers of the form
$$p_ip_{i+1}\cdots p_{j-1}p_j\,,$$
where $i$ and $j$ are integers such that such that $1\leq i\leq j\leq n$.  For example, if we use the enumeration of primes so that $p_1<p_2<p_3<\ldots$, then for $n=3$, $$S=\{2,3,5,2\cdot 3,3\cdot 5,2\cdot 3\cdot 5\}\,.$$

Let $r$ be an arbitrary positive integer.  If $r\leq n$, then the congruence $x^n\equiv s\pmod{p_r}$ has a solution $(x,s)\in\mathbb{Z}\times S$ by taking $x:=0$ and $s:=p_r$.  From now on, we suppose that $r>n$.

Suppose that $g_r$ is a generator of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p_r\mathbb{Z})^\times$.  Suppose that $t_j$ is an integer such that $0\leq t_j <p_r-1$ and $p_j\equiv g_r^{t_j} \pmod{p_r}$, for each $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.  It is [an easy combinatorics exercise using the Pigeonhole Principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699857/proof-subsequence-of-n-integers-is-divisible-by-n) to show that there exist indices $i$ and $j$ such that $1\leq i\leq j \leq n$ and $n$ divides $t_{i}+t_{i+1}+\ldots+t_{j-1}+t_j$.  Thus, by choosing an integer $x$ such that $$x\equiv g_r^{\left(\frac{t_{i}+t_{i+1}+\ldots+t_{j-1}+t_j}{n}\right)}\pmod{p_r}$$
and choosing $s\in S$ to be $p_{i}p_{i+1}\cdots p_{j-1}p_j$, we have $x^n\equiv s\pmod{p_r}$.

**Remark.**  From the proof above, we see that $|S|=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.  What is the smallest possible cardinality of such a set $S$?  Can we find such a set $S$ with fewer than $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ elements?  For $n=2$, it is clear that $|S|\geq 2$, but I have not yet found a way to show that $|S|\geq 3$.

**Related Question.** Does there exist a finite set $S$ of positive integers greater than $1$ such that, for any prime natural number $p$ and for any positive integer $n$, the congruence $x^n\equiv s\pmod{p}$ has a solution $(x,s)\in \mathbb{Z}\times S$?  (The answer is ***no***, per [Carl Schildkraut's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3759424/72152).)

Comment: Actually I suspected it to be using some algebraic number theory but your solution is really nice

Comment: It is well known that a polynomial which has no rational roots but has root modulo p for each prime then degree of the polynomial must be atleast 5 which is proven by chebotarev density theorem

Comment: @Hhhhhhhhhhh  This is me, Batominovski. I am writing from my office's computer, and I couldn't figure out my password.  Would you mind providing a proof of the claim in your comment above (perhaps as an answer, or as a part of your question)?  This claim is not known to me.

Comment: @batominovski the proof is quite hard and hence it's just a difficult known result which uses chebotarev density theorem

Comment: @Hhhhhhhhhhh  Could you please give me some references?

Comment: It is a komal prob and while seeing the sol in pftb they mentioned this fact they have mentioned this fact on page 213

Comment: @Hhhhhhhhhhh  I didn't understand that.  What is a komal prob, and what is pftb?  Also, on Page 213 of which book?

Comment: Search problems from the book on Google and see page 213