# Prove that any sequence $a_1,...a_n$, $n \geq 5$ contains a subsequence whose elements properly added or subtracted give a multiple of $n^2$

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

As in the title:
Prove that any sequence $a_1,...a_n$, $n \geq 5$ contains a subsequence whose elements properly added or subtracted give a multiple of $n^2$

The idea is probably to use the pigeon principle as was done here [For any sequence of $n$ integers, there exists a subsequence whose sum is divisible by $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699857/for-any-sequence-of-n-integers-there-exists-a-subsequence-whose-sum-is-divisi)

This situation is however slightly more complicated. I think we can still produce more than $n^2$ different terms, more specifically we have $2$ choices for the sign of each $a_i$ and hence $2^n$ different terms which is greater than $n^2$ for  $ n \geq 5 $ . However I don't see how to specifically find a term which is divisible by $n^2$ in this case.

Comment: You have three choices for each term, don't you? $+a_i,-a_i,$ and $0$.

Comment: @TonyK You're definitely right, good point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $2^n$ different subsequences, and $2^n>n^2$ for $n\ge 5$. So there exist two different subsequences with the same sum modulo $n^2$. Now just take the first minus the second.

Comment: @CalvinLin: I don't quite see it. Sure, if $n=4$ then either there exist two different subsequences with the same sum, or every residue mod $16$ is represented; and in the second case we can _add_ two subsequences to get a multiple of $16$. But how do we guarantee that these two subsequences have no elements in common? (Or perhaps you had something else in mind?)

Comment: (+1). So say $x= \sum_{n=1}^{n} \alpha_{i,x} a_i$ $y= \sum_{n=1}^{n} \alpha_{i,y} a_i$ with $\alpha_i \in \{-1,0,1 \}.$ I'm not sure whether the difference can still be built within our rules as for example you might have $\alpha_{1,x}=1$, $\alpha_{1,y} =-1$ and hence $\alpha_{1,x-y}=2 \notin \{-1,0,1 \} $

Comment: @TheLionKing: No, unlike my comment, here $\alpha_i\in\{0,1\}$. (That's why I said $2^n$ and not $3^n$.)

Comment: @CalvinLin: for a counterexample when $n=4$, take the sequence $(1,2,4,8)$.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that the emptyset wasn't a pigeon we could use. Note that in your first line it should be $2^n - 1$ then.

Comment: @CalvinLin: no, I was wrong that the subsets have to be non-empty (when I realised this I changed $2^n-1$ to $2^n$, but forgot to delete the non-empty requirement). If you have a subsequence that adds up to a multiple of $n^2$, then subtracting the empty set is a no-op that leaves you with a subsequence adding up to a multiple of $n^2$, as required